# websocket connection closes before a connection is established

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

I have a `NextJS` application that sits behind a nginx reverse proxy. The proxy works successfully except for websockets.

I am getting continuous warning errors in multiple browsers for:

`websocket connection closed before a connection is established`

From the nginx docs, the following websocket config should work, but it still fails?

```
server {
    
    # use docker dns
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;

    #listener port
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    #ssl certificate
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/key.pem;

    #https
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    #websocket
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    #remove buffering error
    proxy_buffers 128 128k;  
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    #optimization
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    #remove 504 known error
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    send_timeout            90;

    upstream up_dev {
        server dev_server:3000;
        keepalive 32; # maximum number of idle keepalive connections to upstream server
    }

    location /app/dev/ {
        proxy_pass http://up_dev/;
    }

    location /app/dev/_next/webpack-hmr {
        proxy_pass http://up_dev/_next/webpack-hmr;
    }
}
```